# My project can find one library header, but not another one

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake

I have two C++ libraries, which I am using on Ubuntu. One of them, let's call it `foo`, I installed through apt-get, e.g. `sudo apt-get install libfoo-dev`. The other, let's call it `bar`, I installed by downloading the source files, and running `make install`. After these installations, I then have header files from `foo` in locations such as `/usr/include/foo/foo.h`, and header files from `bar` in locations such as `/usr/local/include/bar/bar.h`. From my knowledge, `foo` is a dependency of `bar`.

I then created my own C++ project, and included the line `#include "bar/bar.h"`. But when compiling my project, I get an error saying `error: foo.h: No such file or directory`. If I click on the error in my debugger, it opens the file `bar.h`, and highlights the line `#include <foo.h>`. So, my project is able to find `bar.h`, but not `foo.h`. I do not mention either `foo` or `bar` in my `CMakeLists.txt` file.

So my questions are:

1. How does my project know how to find `bar.h`, when I have not told it where to find it in `CMakeLists.txt`?
2. What do I need to do to get my project to find `foo.h` and compile properly?

Thank you!

---

Edit: Here is my `CMakeLists.txt` file (the `foo` and `bar` libraries are none of the ones mentioned here):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -O3")

project(Grasping_Simulator)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR} ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR} ${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR} ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR} ${BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

file(GLOB SRCS *.cpp *.h)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRCS})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${GLEW_LIBRARY} ${GLUT_LIBRARY} ${OpenCV_LIBS} pthread GL boost_system)
```

Comment: It could be installed in /usr/include. Run everything in verbose mode and verify the command line arguments for include paths.

Comment: Some special paths like `/usr/include` and `/usr/local/include` are pre-set in some environment variables like `C_INCLUDE_PATH` or `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`.

Comment: Can you please add your `CMakeLists.txt` (or a minimal version of it)? Just a guess: you have a `find_package()` somewhere. Newer versions are working with [`INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html) where the library can propagate its include directories.

Comment: I've added `CMakeLists.txt`. Perhaps one of the libraries that it looks for, is helping to find `bar.h`?

Comment: @Karnivaurus Thanks. You could do `message(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR} ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR} ${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR} ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR} ${BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})` or list all `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` and check for `bar` with something like `foreach(lib IN ITEMS ${GLEW_LIBRARY} ${GLUT_LIBRARY} ${OpenCV_LIBS} pthread GL boost_system)`|`get_target_property(prop ${lib} INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)`|`message("${lib}: ${prop}")`|`endforeach()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the option `-I/usr/include/foo/` to your compilation command.

By default, locations such as `/usr/include/` and `/usr/local/include` are already in the include search path. However, your library `bar` does something naughty by using `#include <foo.h>`. Really, it should be using things like `#include <foo/foo.h>` (by the way if you can make this change that would be cleaner). That would allow the compiler to search all its include paths, including the path `/usr/include/`, and try appending `/foo/foo.h` - which would succeed. As it stands, there is nothing in the default include path which would work merely by appending `/foo.h`, so it fails to find it.

**EDIT**: Given your CMake code above, most likely you need to append a variable that contains the value `/usr/include/foo` to the `include_directories` line to achieve the desired effect (this being the inclusion of `-I/usr/include/foo/` on the compilation line).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. However, `bar` is quite an established library, so I'd be surprised if it was a result of their bad coding... Perhaps there were some additional instructions that I missed during installation...

Comment: Its most likely they simply expect you to use the option `-I/usr/include/foo/`. There is nothing particularly terrible about this and plenty of 'established libraries' would do something very similar. Its not the cleanest design, but there are few libraries out there that are 'the cleanest'

Comment: @Karnivaurus: the problem is that `bar` developers may have `foo.h` in /usr/include on their machines (or any other location on Windows systems). However on your distro the location is different. This is why there is a problem. As Smeeheey said `foo/foo.h` is the rightest choice. I'd patch `bar` on my computer to fix paths if I were you.